# Cannot find -lbox2d

Tags: c++, box2d, dev-c++

I'm trying to install Box2d, its a physics engine and I having an error:

C:\Program Files\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe | cannot find -lbox2d

I have followed the steps on building it, I have made an .a file named "box2d.a" and moved it to "C:\Program Files\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib" and properly linked it to my compiler named "-lbox2d", I don't know what I've done wrong, I think have build the box2d.a properly but linking it to my compiler is problem, I have tried everything, I've moved it to a different "lib" folder and still having error. 
Please help thank you!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1SJ2gsuT5pQ&t=191s

Answer (score 0):

When you pass `-lx` to the linker (ld). It searches for `libx.so`. This `libx.so` should either be present in the folders known to the linker or you can tell the linker by passing an option with `-L{dir_name}`.

In your case, I can see you are using MinGW (which uses gcc). When you pass `-lbox2d`, you want to have a file named `libbox2d.dll`.

Answer (score 0):

box2d.a looks like a static library, so you must add a "--static" option to your linker settings. Or compile box2d as a shared library (e.g. libbox2d.so)

Comment: Can you please teach me how to do the "--static" option part? I can't figure it how to, I use dev c++.

Comment: sorry, never used dev-c++. using the gcc cmdline it's --static